# How to ignore specific set of words or characters from pattern search in Postgres

Tags: regex, postgresql

I have following table in Postgres 11.

```
col1
BI Placebo
BI 10773 Placebo
AMG 386 Placebo
Eflornithine or Placebo
Sulindac;Placebo
Sulindac plus Placebo
Vehicle Controlled Placebo
```

I would like to fetch those rows where there are specific set of words and special characters ignored and a string has 1 or more before and after the pattern. The desired output is:

```
col1
BI Placebo
BI 10773 Placebo
AMG 386 Placebo
Vehicle Controlled Placebo
```

I tried following query to execute this:

```
select * from table where col1 ~* '^(?!or|;|+|plus)\w\s\w\sPlacebo$' or col1 ~* '^(?!or|;|+|plus)\w\sPlacebo$'
```

My apologies if it is not a complex query but at the moment I am unable to escape those words and characters.

Comment: This is not clear at all and your curretn expression does not clarify what you are doing. Please explain the rules in a clearer way.

Comment: `\w\s\w\s` means "single character + single space + single character + single space" BTW. I feeling that it is not what you really want.

Comment: "string has 1 or more before and after the pattern"  One or more **what**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you allow to match word character only, you can omit matching `;` and `+` from the alternation. Note that you have to escape the plus `\+` or add both to a character class `[;+]`

You can check that the string does not contain *or* and *plus* using the negative lookahead `(?!.*(?:or|plus))`

Then match 1+ word chars using `\w+` followed by optionally match a space and 1+ word chars.

Then match `Placebo` at the end of the string.

```
^(?!.*(?:or|plus))\w+(?: \w+)? Placebo$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/go0uj0/1) | [Postgresql demo](https://rextester.com/NPBR99138)

*For example*

```
select * from table where col1 ~* '^(?!.*(?:or|plus))\w+(?: \w+)? Placebo$'
```

*Output*

**col1**

```
BI Placebo
BI 10773 Placebo
AMG 386 Placebo
Vehicle Controlled Placebo
```